# Question about the conditions that satisfy the Alternating Series Test.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}u_n$ converges if all three of the following conditions are satisfied:

1. The $u_n$'s are all positive.
2. The positive $u_n$'s are (eventually) nonincreasing: $u_n\ge u_{n+1}$ for all $n\ge N$.
3. $u_n \to 0$

This is the definition of the Alternating Series Test from my textbook. I understand the second and third conditions but I do not really understand the significance of the first condition. Since this series is an alternating series, the signs switch from positive to negative so how can all $u_n$'s be positive? Could someone explain the significance of the first condition?

Comment: The **terms** $(-1)^{n+1}u_n$ of the series alternate in sign, since $u_n$ is positive and the $(-1)^{n+1}$ alternates in sign.

Comment: The sequence $(-1)^{n+1} u_n$ may switch signs, but the first condition is saying that $u_n$ itself must all be positive. That is, without $(-1)^{n+1}$.

Comment: That makes more sense! But why is it required that $u_n$ be positive? My textbook doesn't explain this.

Comment: The answer below is good in explaining the reason! It's because then it actually wouldn't necessarily be an alternating series.

Comment: I would prefer to say the terms alternate in sign, and their *absolute values* have limit $0$, and so on. Then series $\sum a_i$ where $a_i$ is negative for odd $n$, and positive for even $n$ don't need to feel discriminated against.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing the individual terms $a_n = (-1)^{n+1}u_n$ with the $u_n$ themselves. In fact, we only have that the series is alternating *because* the $u_n$ are all positive: that means that the $a_n$ change sign every time! As an example for why we need positivity, let's say we picked $u_n = (-1)^{n+1} \frac 1n$. Then our series becomes $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{2n+2} \frac 1n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1n$$ By not restricting the $u_n$ to be positive, our sequence (the $a_n = \frac 1n$) no longer alternates signs.

Comment: I see, but if $u_n$ is negative, wouldn't the signs just shift one place to the right or left?

Comment: Yes, that's true. It's really only convenience that we say "all $u_n$ are positive" instead of "all positive OR all negative". But since we only care about convergence, and $-\sum (-1)^n u_n = \sum (-1)^{n+1} u_n$, one converges if and only if the other does - so we can just multiply it by $-1$ to make all the $u_n$ positive.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this so clearly!

Comment: Gladly!$\ \ \ $